# Improve SQL INSERT query to avoid sql injections

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sql-injection, sql-insert

I am using pymyql/mysql-connector to write the messages to mysql database. The messages are processed on callback (paho.mqtt callback) from mqtt broker.I have 4 different tables and based on the message type, I am inserting messages into database. I have written the insert queries as below. this way of writing leads to sql injections it seems.Any suggestions how can I improve the insert query statements?

```
# callback attached to paho.mqtt.client    
def on_message(self, client, userdata, msg):

    if  msg.topic.startswith("topic1/"):
        self.bulkpayload += "(" + msg.payload.decode("utf-8") + "," + datetime + "),"
    elif msg.topic.startswith("topic2/"):
        self.insertStatement += "INSERT INTO mydatabase.table1 VALUES (" + msg.payload.decode("utf-8") + "," + datetime + ");"
    elif msg.topic.startswith("topic3/")   
        self.insertStatement += "INSERT INTO mydatabase.table2 VALUES (" +msg.payload.decode("utf-8") + "," + datetime + ");"
    elif msg.topic.startswith("messages"):
        self.insertStatement += "INSERT INTO mydatabase.table3 VALUES ('" + msg.topic + "',"  + msg.payload.decode("utf-8") + "," + datetime + ");"
    else:
    return  # do not store in DB

    cursor.execute(self.insertStatement)
    cursor.commit()
```

Comment: Validate your user input before you send the query and use query parameters.

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with Python syntax but can you make your insert statement parameterised? That will help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your query use parameters. Much less chance of injection:

`cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (var1, var2, var3))`

credit (and more info) here: [How to use variables in SQL statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python)

Also, Dan Bracuk is correct - make sure you validate your params before executing the SQL if you aren't already

Comment: Can I use like this `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (msg.payload.decode("utf-8"), var3))`

Comment: I think so yes...I'm not an expert on Python syntax...give it a try anyway! You will be able to work out the best solution for you then. Note the example has three `%s` placeholders but you are only accounting for 2 of them.

Comment: `msg.payload.decode("utf-8")` holds the value for first two (%s,%s) placeholders. I am not sure if this will work. I will try. otherwise, I have to split the values contained in payload and map to placeholders. Thank you.

Comment: Ah ok so is it an array? Either way I'm pretty certain you will need to take the value/values and work them so that your SQL statement has a value for placeholder 1 and 2 separately.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html
https://www.athenic.net/posts/2017/Jan/21/preventing-sql-injection-in-python/